# Dynamic mask for EditText using TextWatcher (for Blood Pressue unit)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, masking, input-mask

I want to mask `EditText` for Blood Pressure unit, for example (###/###).

value can be `2digits/2digits` or `3digits/3digits` or `3digits/2digits` or `2digits/3digits`

Currently I'm using below code which is working fine for `2digits/2digits` or `3digits/3digits` or `3digits/2digits` not working for `2digits/3digits`.

**here is my code:**

```
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

object EditTextBPMask {
    private const val mask22 = "##/##"
    private const val mask32 = "###/##"
    private const val mask33 = "###/###"

    fun unmask(s: String): String {
        return s.replace("[^0-9]*".toRegex(), "")
    }

    fun insert(editText: EditText): TextWatcher {
        return object : TextWatcher {
            var isUpdating: Boolean = false
            var old = ""

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                val str = unmask(s.toString())
                val mask: String
                val defaultMask = getDefaultMask(str)
                mask = when (str.length) {
                    6 -> mask33
                    5 -> mask32
                    else -> defaultMask
                }

                var mascara = ""
                if (isUpdating) {
                    old = str
                    isUpdating = false
                    return
                }
                var i = 0
                for (m in mask.toCharArray()) {
                    if (m != '#' && str.length > old.length || m != '#' && str.length < old.length && str.length != i) {
                        mascara += m
                        continue
                    }

                    try {
                        mascara += str[i]
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        break
                    }

                    i++
                }
                isUpdating = true
                editText.setText(mascara)
                editText.setSelection(mascara.length)
                /*if (isValid(editText)) {
                    editText.error = null
                }
                else {
                    editText.error = "Incorrect value!"
                }*/
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
        }
    }

    private fun getDefaultMask(str: String): String {
        var defaultMask = mask22
        if (str.length > 6) {
            defaultMask = mask33
        }
        return defaultMask
    }

    fun isValid(editText: EditText): Boolean {
        return if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.text.toString())) {
            unmask(editText.text.toString()).length > 3
        }
        else {
            false
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to implement, if done properly, would eventually require you to use a state machine as in [regular expressions](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/finite-state-machines-and-regular-expressions-r3176).

From a cursory glance, your solution is missing some key points, like handling situations when cursor is not at the end of the string; thus, your solution won't properly handle pasting from the clipboard, too.

Next, you've got to use the `::afterTextChanged` method with its `Editable` variable in order to make changes within your `EditText` "on the fly", simultaneously with user typing.

I'd rather encourage you to incorporate an established solution, and there're quite a few. I see you already have Kotlin runtime in your project, thus you'll be able to pull in libraries like [RedMadRobot/input-mask-android](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android). The library allows to switch between formats depending on user input, and I've got to mention that I'm a maintainer of it, so feel free to ask any questions regarding its usage.

Other honourable mentions:

- [pinball83/Masked-Edittext](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext)
- [santalu/mask-edittext](https://github.com/santalu/mask-edittext)
- [egslava/edittext-mask](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)
- [TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro)
- [PaXLiCh/FormattEditText](https://github.com/PaXLiCh/FormattEditText)

— though I'm not sure any of these would actually handle your particular case with values of different length.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with another solution instead of using masked input. Here's my logic I implemented in my app:

The regex for blood pressure will be `[0-9]{0,3}/[0-9]{0-3}`. But instead of putting only the `/`, use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` to prevent any letter and number to be inserted at the `/` position, and for us to change the `.` in decimal field to `/` later.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    final int maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint=3;
    final int maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint=3;

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
        builder.replace(dstart, dend, source
                .subSequence(start, end).toString());
        if (!builder.toString().matches(
                "(([1-9]{1})([0-9]{0,"+(maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint-1)+"})?)?([^a-zA-z0-9][0-9]{0,"+maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint+"})?"

        )) {
            if(source.length()==0)
                return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Then, create a `TextWatcher` for the `editText` as well. The first if statement is to prevent the `.` being displayed in the `editText`, since the `editText` is set to `android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"`. For the second and third if statements is to validate 2 digit inputs and 3 digit inputs respectively. You can add on the logic on validating the inputs after the `/` as well :).

```
bloodPressureAm.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});
bloodPressureAm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (String.valueOf(bloodPressureAm.getText()).contains(".")){
            bloodPressureAm.setText(String.valueOf(bloodPressureAm.getText()).replace(".","/"));
        }
        //Means it's going to insert 100+
        if (editable.length() == 2 && !isDeleting){
            if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(bloodPressureAm.getText())) >= 20){
                bloodPressureAm.setText(bloodPressureAm.getText() + "/");
            }
        }
        if (editable.length() == 3 && !isDeleting){
            if (!String.valueOf(bloodPressureAm.getText()).contains("/")){
                bloodPressureAm.setText(bloodPressureAm.getText() + "/");
            }
        }
        //Set the cursor to the end of the editText
        bloodPressureAm.setSelection(bloodPressureAm.getText().length());
    }
});
```

Lastly, since we forced the `/` to be inserted after 2 or 3 digits, we are unable to delete it due to the `TextWatcher`. So, to overcome it, create a `onKeyListener` for `editText`.

```
bloodPressureAm.setOnKeyListener((view, i, keyEvent) -> {
    if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        isDeleting = true;
    }else{
        isDeleting = false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps! >:>